# Navigation property does not reset to null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple application, that registers a `collection` of money from batches of sold tickets from
drivers (which domain expert calls `settlements`). I try to use DDD approach and EF Core to handle this small app (call it a playground for using EF Core in DDD). I have basically 3 tables in SQL Server (simplified to the absolute minimum):

```
Table: Collection
-------------+---------
   Column    | Type    
-------------+---------
CollectionId | int (PK)    
IsCancelled  | bit
```

```
Table: Settlement
-------------+---------
   Column    | Type    
-------------+---------
SettlementId | int (PK)
CollectionId | int (FK)
Number       | int
```

```
Table: CollectionSettlementJoin
-------------+---------
   Column    | Type    
-------------+---------
SettlementId | int (PK)(FK)
CollectionId | int (PK)(FK)
```

I know there seems to be a redundant join table (since I have the `CollectionId` on the `Settlement` table), but it seems to be a design requirement, that I will explain in a moment. So each `collection` has at least 1 or more `settlements`. I have 2 domain entities which actually correspond with the tables - my aggregate root `Collection` and attached to it `Settlements` property that contains list of `Settlement` entities.
The extra table is used for auditing purposes as actually does not take real part in the domain. It is populated by a trigger on `Settlement.CollectionId` update (for non-nulls). Each `collection` can be cancelled within 5 minutes of its creation by the creator or anytime by a superuser. When a `collection` is cancelled, I want to reset `Settlement.CollectionId` to `null` (when that happens data in `CollectionSettlementJoin` stays and I can always get back what settlements were cancelled).

My current setup is working fine when comes to creating a `collection`. The selected `settlements` are added, saved and successfully persisted in my database. The problem starts when I want to cancel a collection. I get from the database the `collection` with attached `settlements` . But when I remove the `settlements` from my aggregate root, `dbContext.SaveChanges()` does not persist the changes (does not set `Settlement.CollectionId` to `null`).

Here is my setup:

```cs
public class Collection : EntityBase, IAggregateRoot
{
    private Collection() { }
    public Collection(List<Settlement> settlements)
        {
            _settlements = settlements;
        }
    private bool _isCancelled;
    public bool IsCancelled => _isCancelled;

    private List<Settlement> _settlements;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Settlement> Settlements => _settlements.AsReadOnly();

    public void CancelCollection()
    {
        if (_isCancelled != true)
        {
            _isCancelled = true;
            _settlements.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Settlement : EntityBase
{
    private Settlement() { }
    public Collection? Collection { get;set; }
    public int? CollectionId { get; internal set; }
}
```

```cs
public class CollectionEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Collection>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Collection> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Collection");
        builder.HasKey(s => s.Id);
        builder.Property(s => s.Id).HasColumnName("CollectionId").UseIdentityColumn();
        builder.Property(s => s.IsCancelled).HasDefaultValueSql("(0)");
        builder.HasMany(s => s.Settlements)
            .WithOne(c => c.Collection)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.CollectionId);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class SettlementEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Settlement>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Settlement> builder)
    {            
        builder.ToTable("Settlement");
        builder.HasKey(s => s.Id);
        builder.Property(s => s.Id).HasColumnName("SettlementId").ValueGeneratedNever();
        builder.Property(s => s.CollectionId);
        builder.HasOne(s => s.Collection)
            .WithMany(c => c.Settlements)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.CollectionId);                
    }
}
```

Context (not much here)

```cs
public class SettlementCollectionContext: DbContext
{        
    public SettlementCollectionContext(
        DbContextOptions<SettlementCollectionContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.StateChanged += ChangeTracker_StateChanged;
    }

    private void ChangeTracker_StateChanged(object sender, EntityStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Entity {e.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name} has changed.");
    }

    public DbSet<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Settlement> Settlements { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new SettlementEntityTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CollectionEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }
}
```

And finally my command:

```cs
var collection = await _dbContext.Collections
    .Include(c => c.Settlements)
    .Where(c => c.Id == collectionId)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

if (!collection!.IsCancelled)
    {
        collection.CancelCollection();
    }

_dbContext.Update(collection); //without this the change tracker does not register the change
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I know that the `ChangeTracker` registeres this change, becuase I added in my context an even handler to `ChangeTracker.StateChanged` and during debugging I noticed it register that `collection` has changed (although not the `settlement`). I also tried to reset `Settlement.CollectionId` property to `null` in `Collection.CancelCollection()` method, but this did not help either. I must be missing something.

Comment: Just for clarity, what EF Core version are you targeting (because there are some changes in behavior between EF Core versions)?

Comment: I am doing this in EF core 5.0 preview 8. Although I think I could revert (temporarily?) to 3.1?

Comment: No, the question was just to be able to reproduce.

Comment: So as I wrote - EF Core 5.0.

Comment: Yes, got it - "No" was for reverting to 3.1, don't do that. Anyway, tried your model and code as posted, and the `CollectionId` of the related `Settlement` is set to null in both memory and database. And btw, the same happens if you skip `_dbContext.Update(collection);` line - contrary to your code comment, change tracker detects the collection clear the next time you call some change tracking  method. There must be something in your real model/configuration not shown here which is causing the issue.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Now I feel ashamed I did not check the basic config as I wrote it here. It would have taken me less time and I would not waste your time. Please accept my apologies. Anyway - my problem in the end is that my unit of work was committing transaction of incorrect context (in this special scenario I actually have more than 1 bounded context that spawns 2 ef contexts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end nothing is wrong with the setup. Actually my unit of work was a problem, because it was saving incorrect context, so obviously the changes were never persisted.